# RecyclerView.Adapter loading image from URL does not get updated

Tags: android, picasso, android-viewholder

I am having a problem to update an image in `RecylcerView.Adapter` on change.  I am having this class for my Adapter:

```
public class ShowMembersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowMembersAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<User> users;
    private Context context;
    private ShowTeamsAdapter.OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ShowTeamsAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CircleImageView mImage;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, ShowTeamsAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ShowMembersAdapter(ArrayList<User> users, Context context) {
        this.users = users;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ShowMembersAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_member_item, parent, false);
        ShowMembersAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ShowMembersAdapter.ViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ShowMembers
        String imageUrl = "MYURL" + users.get(position).getEmail() + ".jpg";
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).resize(200,200).error(R.mipmap.ic_team_member_no_photo).into(holder.mImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }
}
```

I am populating this class from my `Fragment`. It works perfectly when I start an application. However, whenever I update the picture from application, I guess that adapter won't change because the image URL is still the same. Do you have any other ideas, that I can do? Do you think I should call one more Volley request to get Images and save them to each User, so I don't call them directly from `Adapter`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Picasso will cache your images into local storage for improve loading speed. In your case, the image URL is not changed, so it does't know that it must fetch from URL again. You have to clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks for this! However, it only works when I call this method `PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.get());` in an activity that displays User detail. In Fragment where I show many users, I don't know where to call `clearCache()`. Because when I put it in adapter I guess onBindViewHolder is not called anymore after the first run...

Comment: In real world, cache in storage and memory is the good way to improve image loading speed. You should not worry about the same image URL but different image content. If you want Picasso must fetch from URL every time, they provide `skipMemoryCache`, `MemoryPolicy ` with `NO_CACHE ` and `NO_STORE `. You can have further information from Picasso document here: http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/

Answer (score 1):

After updating your picture, have you tried this:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```